# Inserting data in MySQL database using JS

Tags: javascript, php

I have this basic HTML page and there is a form to upload data to a MySQL database.

There is also a JavaScript that passes data to the `process.php` file. Into this file, I have an `INSERT` query. I use this script because I do not want to reload the page on submit.

Now I have 2 problems:

**1)** When I send data to the MySQL table (clicking on submit button), the first time **1 data = 1 record** inserted and this is correct. If I insert a new data into the input form field, I have **1 data = 2 records** equal. The third time, 3 records and so on...

But if I print what is passed by `POST` with `print_r($_POST)`, I have always one data Array `( [comune] => foo )`.

I also tried to use `unset()` without success.

**2)** When I click for the first time on submit button, there's no action, I have to click twice.

This is the HTML page with the JS script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".formValidation").validate({
            debug: false,
            rules: {
              name: "required",
              email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
              }
            },
            messages: {
              name: "Please let us know who you are.",
              email: "A valid email will help us get in touch with you.",
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
              // do other stuff for a valid form
              $('.formValidation').on('submit', function () {
                $.post('process.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){
                  $('#results').html(data);
                });
              })
            }
        });
      }); 
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <form id="myform2" class="formValidation" name="myform2" action="" method="post"></form>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
          <div class="widget-box">
            <div class="widget-body">
              <div class="widget-main">
                <div>
                  <label for="form-field-select-1">form</label>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="widget-body">
                  <div class="widget-main">
                    <div>
                      <input type="text" name="comune" id="comune" value="" placeholder="Add something" form="myform2">
                      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" form="myform2">
                      <p id="result"></p>
                      <div id="results"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.col -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
  </body>
</html>
```

and the `process.php`

```
foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
  $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_".$key."(nome_".$key.") VALUES ('$value')";
  $result = dbQuery($sql);
  unset($key);
  unset($value);
}
```

Comment: yikes - you are asking for a serious sql injectionattack!

Comment: It's only for a test purpose

Answer (score 2):

You have too many submit handlers.

Just do the ajax in the `submitHandler` callback option of the plugin.

Internally it is already doing the `on('submit')` so the first time you click it...the handler you wrote to do the ajax is created but isn't sending yet

The next time it will actually send the form twice and add another submit handler. A third click would send 3 times and add another submit handler and so on

```
submitHandler: function(form) { // fires only when valid                      
     $.post('process.php', $(form).serialize(), function(data) {
        $('#results').html(data);
     });
}
```

Comment: in this way i send to process.php all the names for all <form> present in this page and the values are empty 

Array ( [cboCategory] => [txtName] => [mtxDescription] => [comune] => )

I need to send only the values of .formValidation class

Answer (score 0):

your submit handlers are stacking one by one.. and each time requests to the php files increases, causing inserting more than once in database.

Use

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
                        $.post('process.php', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
                            $('#results').html(data);
                        });
                        return false;
                }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: What i have in process.php via POST is an empty array. Ok, maybe i forgot to say that this is an example. On my real page i have more than one <form> and i need to send to process file, only the value of .formValidation form class. Thanks